# Sharepoint REST api - post a like on a site page comment

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I can like a page using:
POST

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('SitePages')/GetItemById(722)/like
```

Modern pages also allow users to like a comment but this api call doesn't work:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('SitePages')/GetItemById(<pageid>)/Comments(<commentid>)/like
```

Error:

```
"error": {
"code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
"message": {
"lang": "en-US",
"value": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."
}
```

I'm posting as a user who can like a comment in the browser and is an SP admin and site coll admin; the page is published with comments enabled and a comment posted, so what is it exactly that's unauthorized?

Comment: From where are you trying to "like" the comment? From SPFx web part? Same SharePoint site? Did you add all necessary "headers" for POST operation?

Comment: The access token got corrupted - working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though not visually apparent, Postman was corrupting the access token in one request that was working in others. Once I started from scratch, it worked.